# How do I disable Explorer View for select users in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0?

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

How do I disable Explorer View for select users in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0?

Setting specific permissions becomes useless when my users could just go into explorer view and start deleting.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Explorer view should respect the permissions you've set up on the site

Answer (score 0):

I also have the simillar problem. And explorer view does not respect the permission set up on the site.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge this is not possible because explorer view relies on webdav, which is on or off for a site/location, not for a specific user.